# Ordered execution for a Python asyncio.Semaphore

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

I'm running a number of  parallel executions with `asyncio.Semaphore` over an ordered `List`.

```
    async def send_cus(cus_id):
        async with ClientSession(connector=TCPConnector(limit=0)) as session:
            num_parallel = asyncio.Semaphore(20)

            async def send_cust_2(cust_id):
                async with num_parallel:
                    # do something ...

            tasks = list(
                send_cust_2(cust_id)
                for cus_id in my_ordered_lst
            )
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

The point is that it executes in an unordered manner, regardless of the `my_ordered_lst` order. I understand it is because we cannot get guaranteed the execution order for threads or process-forks without syncing elements.

Is there a way to get an ordered execution throughout the `List`, while still having a parallel execution? Like first send 1st. acquire the lock, the send then send, acquire the lock, and so on.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how you expect ordered-but-parallel execution to work? I'm not sure I understand your last paragraph.

Comment: Yes, it is a little confusing. The idea is to launch first the 1st element of the list, then launch the second, without having to wait until the first task ends. And so on.

Comment: That's precisely what `gather` does, AFAIK - try adding a `print` at the beginning of `send_cust_2` to test it.

Comment: Yes, I've added a `print` in `send_cust_2()` and I can see that the execution order is different on each execution.

Comment: I get _random_ output: https://pastebin.com/KyU06mDn

Comment: Which Python version are you using? I am running Python 3.7.

Comment: Python 3.6.8. I don't think the execution order could be affected by the Python version, do you?

Comment: `gather` was rewritten for 3.7, so it can, yes.

Comment: Using harryPoker's code from pastebin, Python3.8 gives perfectly ordered output, 0-99 in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to Python 3.7, `asyncio.gather()` started the tasks in an arbitrary order. For 3.7 it was [rewritten for efficiency](https://bugs.python.org/issue32355) with the side effect that it now creates the tasks in the order specified.

In Python 3.6 and earlier you can work around the issue by spawning the tasks manually in the desired order, and then calling `gather` to wait for them to finish:

```py
tasks = [asyncio.create_task(send_cust_2(cust_id))
         for cust_id in my_ordered_lst]
await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Note that this will just *start* the tasks in the specified order. How they proceed executing past the first `await` will depend on what the individual tasks do and the timings of their respective operations.